# Auto-generated rspecs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, scaffold

I am working on an existing RoR app which was written a few years ago. It's testers were less than satisfying so the whole `/spec` directory was removed and I have to write new rspecs. I have seen somewhere that it is possible to generate non-blank rspecs using scaffold method. When I tried doing

```
rails generate scaffold rspec:model User
```

I got the lovely result of

```
invoke  active_record
/home/guy/railsProjects/netAdmin/vendor/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:258:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name Rspec:model (NameError)
    from /home/guy/railsProjects/netAdmin/vendor/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:258:in `block in class_collisions'
```

how do I work it out? having something that will write some of the specs, based on the existing models and controllers will save me tons of time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some things to check: Do you have the `gem 'rspec-rails'` available in both development (for the generator) and test environments? And have you run rails `generate rspec:install`? And if so, what's your gem version?

Comment: of course I have them. my rspec version is 2.14.1

nifty-generator adds some auto-made test to scaffolds that you create, but I look for something that will see my existing model and will write an appropriate spec. is this possible?

Comment: I've never seen it, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Regardless, your command should be passing and creating the spec files I would think.